# Почему возникает ошибка "Incorrect syntax near'" при выполнении select

Tags: sql

```
select int, out from income_o full join outcome_o
```

Почему выдается след ошибка.

> `Ошибка.
> Incorrect syntax near ';'.`

Comment: отсутствует 'on'. 
азбучные истины нужно постигать в другом месте ).
Ну а если это просто невнимательность (что бывает с каждым) - то вопрос не интересен, не несет никакой информации

Answer (score 2):

Таблица с инками должна объединяться с таблицей с аутками по какому-то полю, например:

```
SELECT int, out
FROM income_o
FULL JOIN outcome_o ON outcome_o.inc_id = income_o.id
```

Либо, если просто необходимо выбрать все значения, то джоин не нужен, просто указываются имена таблиц:

```
SELECT int, out
FROM income_o, outcome_o
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы не указали, куда и по какому полю собираетесь джойниться.

Comment: вроде указал, таблица инком полное внешнее обьединение с таблице оуткам
поподробнее плз а то не доходит)

Comment: там отсутствует условие связи (инструкция ON) - например указание полей связи   связываемых таблиц

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно декартово соединение, используйте CROSS JOIN, а не FULL. FULL подразумевает, что вы соединяетесь по определенному полю (т.е. требуется оператор ON ...), и означает, что вам необходимо вернуть значения и из левой и из правой таблицы, даже если им не нашлось соответствующих значений.